# SQL Server Query XML in Nvarchar(max) Field?

Tags: sql-server, xquery-sql

I have XML stored in an nvarchar(max) field.  I realize there is an XML data type, but in this case it is not stored that way. Let's say the XML is structured like the following:

```
<root>
<hdr>
  <name>aj</name>
</hdr>
<dtls>
  <dtl>
    <price>1</price>
  </dtl>
  <dtl>
    <price>7</price>
  </dtl>
  <dtl>
    <price>3</price>
  </dtl>
</dtls>
</root>
```

What I am trying to do is get the count of detail (dtl) nodes that exist for record.  I am sure this is possible with xpath/xquery, I am just not exactly sure how.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CAST(<YOUR_XML_COLUMN> AS XML).query('count(//dtl)')
  FROM <YOUR_TABLE>
```

e.g:

```
DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @x = '<root> <hdr>   <name>aj</name> </hdr> <dtls>   <dtl>     <price>1</price>   </dtl>   <dtl>     <price>7</price>   </dtl>   <dtl>     <price>3</price>   </dtl> </dtls> </root>'
SELECT CAST(@x AS XML).query('count(//dtl)')
```

Comment: @+1 - would he need to cast his `nvarchar` as `xml` for this to work?